# How to make "this command cannot found" discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm a bot developer and I own a music bot. I want to make this: how to make this command cannot found discord.js (I mean if someonee enter a command like `m!pla` then bot will say "U mean this? `m!play`")

Answer (score 1):

You can use the npm package [meant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meant). It uses the [Levenshtein Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.) algorithm to find the most likely match given a string and an array of strings to compare it to.

```js
const meant = require('meant');
const result = meant('foa', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) // => [ 'foo' ]
```

All you need is an array of your command names, and the command the user tried to execute.

```js
const meant = require('meant');
const [result] = meant(commandName, commandNames);

// Did you mean ${result}?
```